# toolkit & methods for extracting text bounds in 'searchable pdf'

Tags: java, pdf

I have a "searchable pdf" aka 'image files with invisible but selectable text'.  (When this file is opened in Acrobat, I am alerted "You are viewing this document in PDF/A mode.")

I need to extract the bounding rectangle of each word in this document.  Any suggested toolkits and the methods for accessing the "invisi-text" words' bounding-boxes?

I would prefer tools in java, but appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat's javascript libraries look to be the most straightforward, especially:

```
getPageNthWordQuads
```

which works on a "searchable pdf".

Would be nice if the acrobat javascript library was available as java calls...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the iText library: http://www.lowagie.com/iText/

Comment: iText is primarily for generating pdf documents.  I don't see anything in the api for extracting bounding box information for text in loaded pdfs.

Comment: Yep you are correct. Sorry about the bum steer. Perhaps http://support.idrsolutions.com/default.asp?W17 is a better bet?

Answer (score 0):

PdfBox and JPedal also offer text extraction methods.

Comment: I downloaded the JPedal demo jar, but (1) the xml it exported did not have bounding box info; and (2) when I did plain text extraction it did not return the "searchable"/invisi- text (I assume it tried to do OCR?)